# Imitate sound of waves

Tags: doppler, fx

I need to create algorithm for sound of waves. So I imagine it should be a white noise with doppler effect. However I understand doppler is just change of frequency. But white noise have all the frequencies in it.

How do I create it? I need an explanation of what constitutes sound of sea waves which moves forward and back rithmically

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because coding questions would be better asked on [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: OK. Describe the essence of a solution in natural language